# OpenSSL crashes with Sig11 while validating certificate

Tags: c++, linux, qt, openssl

I have built openssl version 1.0.2h as below,

```
./Configure -d shared no-idea no-mdc2 no-rc5 debug-linux-x86_64 --prefix=@rpath --openssldir=.
```

I have got the below libraries built

```
libssl.so.1.0.2
libcrypto.so.1.0.2
```

I have linked this libraries with my C++ application along with Qt 5.0.0. When I run my application it crashes with `segmentation fault` with the following stack trace,

```
Thread #1 22887 (Suspended : Container) 
        trust_1oidany() at x509_trs.c:270 0x7f66362255a9    
        X509_check_trust() at x509_trs.c:134 0x7f6636225141 
        check_trust() at x509_vfy.c:807 0x7f663621c212  
        X509_verify_cert() at x509_vfy.c:370 0x7f663621b3f5 
        ssl_verify_cert_chain() at 0x3f2a2469b8 
        ssl3_get_server_certificate() at 0x3f2a2255f3   
        ssl3_connect() at 0x3f2a227ca2  
        q_SSL_connect() at qsslsocket_openssl_symbols.cpp:229 0x7f6639b1064a    
        QSslSocketBackendPrivate::startHandshake() at qsslsocket_openssl.cpp:1,128 0x7f6639b0af78   
        QSslSocketBackendPrivate::transmit() at qsslsocket_openssl.cpp:983 0x7f6639b0a4ea   
        QSslSocketPrivate::_q_readyReadSlot() at qsslsocket.cpp:2,431 0x7f6639afcbc3    
        QSslSocket::qt_static_metacall() at moc_qsslsocket.cpp:167 0x7f6639afdc79   
        QMetaObject::activate() at qobject.cpp:3,739 0x7f663907dab6 
        QMetaObject::activate() at qobject.cpp:3,604 0x7f663907d2b6 
        QIODevice::readyRead() at moc_qiodevice.cpp:155 0x7f6639115081  
        QAbstractSocketPrivate::canReadNotification() at qabstractsocket.cpp:730 0x7f6639ad4bc6 
        QAbstractSocketPrivate::readNotification() at qabstractsocket_p.h:69 0x7f6639adae1a 
        QAbstractSocketEngine::readNotification() at qabstractsocketengine.cpp:152 0x7f6639ac6701   
        QReadNotifier::event() at qnativesocketengine.cpp:1,169 0x7f6639ae3a06  
        QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper() at qapplication.cpp:3,753 0x7f6637647b22   
        QApplication::notify() at qapplication.cpp:3,197 0x7f66376451dc 
        QCoreApplication::notifyInternal() at qcoreapplication.cpp:965 0x7f663903eb36   
        QCoreApplication::sendEvent() at qcoreapplication.h:224 0x7f66390428c7  
        socketNotifierSourceDispatch() at qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp:101 0x7f66390b5450  
        g_main_context_dispatch() at 0x3f1aa40642   
        0x3f1aa44c98    
        g_main_context_iteration() at 0x3f1aa44e4c  
        QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents() at qeventdispatcher_glib.cpp:418 0x7f66390b6199   
        QEventLoop::processEvents() at qeventloop.cpp:128 0x7f663903b712    
        QEventLoop::exec() at qeventloop.cpp:204 0x7f663903b9f5 
        QThread::exec() at qthread.cpp:522 0x7f6638df9000   
        QThread::run() at qthread.cpp:589 0x7f6638df91a6    
        QThreadPrivate::start() at qthread_unix.cpp:338 0x7f6638e00683  
        start_thread() at 0x3f19a07aa1  
        clone() at 0x3f192e8aad
```

When I did debug this, the below line has some invalid pointer dereference,

```
if (x->aux && (x->aux->trust || x->aux->reject))
```

But I'm unable to trace out what's causing that. I do not have any pointer to proceed further with this issue. could someone shed light on this.

Comment: The only possibility is that x is NULL, but why x is NULL is a thing that only the application writer knows.    
Add a test e.g. `if (x && x->aux && (x->aux->trust || x->aux->reject))` and see what happens.

Comment: @FaraImportanta Yes you are right. There is a NULL dreference but `x` is not `NULL`. The `x` is of data type `X509` and it contains some valid data but the `x->aux` is `NULL`. The actual problematic location is in the `openssl->1.0.2h/crypto/x509/x509_trs.c` line number 270.

Comment: I would like to understand why `x->aux` of `X509` is NULL. Do I miss anything here.

Comment: Well, the answer lies within the X509 certificate that your application uses, in this case.

Comment: You should show the callback you are using - `trust_1oidany` is not part of OpenSSL. You can also get better debug builds by following [Compilation and Installation | Debug Configuration](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Debug_Configuration) from the OpenSSL wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root cause for this issue. The `openssl` libraries which I built locally does not include `-rpath`, thus the `libssl.so` is unable to find `libcrypto.so`, hence the issue. So I updated `Configure` to include `-rpath` as indicated [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Using_RPATHs). Also please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584754/build-openssl-1-0-2h-with-multiple-rpath-for-linux?noredirect=1#comment64576507_38584754) on how I managed to include multiple `-rpath` option. Despite I'm not sure whether this is legitimate way of doing it but the solution works for me.